# What is the best way to learn .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to learn the .htaccess file, where to start from ?
I need a simple tutorials at tge begining not a professional document

I want to know how to prevent specific files from being accessed direcly .. and hiw to setup a route redirect

Comment: this is not a php question. Also it is to generic, what do you try to do with htaccess?

Comment: I want to know how to prevent specific files from being accessed direcly .. and hiw to setup a route redirect

Comment: You can try this link https://amitoverflow.com/2021/04/15/htaccess-tutorial-for-beginers/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's lots of tutorials out in the net, this is one great tutorial for htaccess: [htaccess-guide](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/). Very much examples, and good explanations.
You can find more tutorials by using [google](http://goo.gl/Jfd087).